# "Across" + "from" structure

Tags: meaning

1. **Across** the street.
2. **Across** the street **from** ...
3. **Across from** the street.
4. **Across from** the street **from** the church.

I know what the first phrase means but I have problem with the rest.

What they mean?

Edit:

Examples:

> 1. He argued that it was **across from street** and I had given wrong address then.
> 2. Entrance to the Front Beach **across from** street **from** our house.
> 3. The two-story, 232,000-square foot facility sprawls on 50 acres along Route 108, **across from street from** stately mansions erected on...
> 4. Hayward stayed at a hotel in South Jersey **across from street from** the Garden State Racetrack

Comment: Your added examples don't make much sense. They seem to be missing vital words...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the third example appears in the [Baltimore Sun](http://articles.baltimoresun.com/1995-02-12/news/1995043081_1_ellicott-mills-building-schools-new-schools), I think it's a misprint. Similarly for the fourth example from [Fight News](http://www.fightnews.com/Boxing/throwback-fight-ennis-rosado-52697).

These should say ***across the street from***. I believe that the articles originally used *across from* — that is, "...sprawls along Rote 108, across from stately mansions..." and "a hotel in South Jersey across from the Garden State Racetrack".

*Across from* generally means "across the street" because that's the most usual point of reference; but it could be across anything: a river, a park, you name it. The subeditor realised that and attempted to insert *street* and got it wrong.

Answer (score 4):

1) anywhere on the other side of the street.

2) on the other side as seen from a specific location on your side of the street.

3) and 4) They hardly make sense on their own, maybe you have a little context to add?

For example : Nina is an interesting woman who sits across from me at work.

Answer (score 0):

The added examples of "across from street" all sound simply wrong to me.  But I can't rule out the possibility that they would sound OK in some English-speaking places.